# Why matplotlib plot axis is not strictly set to equal when figsize is set to same value for width and height

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Using following code to get axis position and the ration of weight and height.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ss = 2.4
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(ss, ss))
box = ax.get_position()
box.width/box.height
```

Set `ss=2.4, 3.6, 7.2`, the output in my PC is always the same:

> **1.0064935064935066**

Backend: %matplotlib qt

Why not get the width and height the same value?

Comment: Any reason to have such inconstancy? Any numerical consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is per se no reason that an axes should be square, just because the figure it lives in is square.

The subplot parameters set by the [default rc file](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file) are

> ```
> figure.subplot.left    : 0.125  ## the left side of the subplots of the figure
> figure.subplot.right   : 0.9    ## the right side of the subplots of the figure
> figure.subplot.bottom  : 0.11   ## the bottom of the subplots of the figure
> figure.subplot.top     : 0.88   ## the top of the subplots of the figure
> ```

such that

```
(right-left)/(top-bottom) = (0.9-0.125)/(0.88-0.11) = 1.0064935
```

Of course you can set those parameters to your liking and hence optain a square subplot, either in your rc file, or via code, e.g.

```
rc = {"figure.subplot.left"    : 0.1, 
      "figure.subplot.right"   : 0.9,
      "figure.subplot.bottom"  : 0.1,
      "figure.subplot.top"     : 0.9 }
plt.rcParams.update(rc)
```

or

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9)
```

Comment: Thanks, one more way to generate square axes are fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]), which is is useful for me to fine tune the position of the axes.